# Excel VBA/Outlook Send e-mail unencrypted

Tags: excel, vba, encryption, outlook, office-automation

The code I am working on currently generates a message, saves as a draft for others to send and then attaches that draft to another e-mail. However, I need the attached draft to remain unencrypted for others to be able to send. As my center's policies automatically encrypt e-mails by default, I am attempting to only set the property for the initial draft. Otherwise, members are unable to open the file.

```
Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

OMail.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, -4

With OMail
.To = "xx@gmail.com"
.Subject = "subjecthere " & currdate
.Body = CCbody1 & ccprice & CCbody2
.Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
.Save
End With
  On Error GoTo 0
```

Unfortunately, running the code mentioned from comments here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dvespa/how-to-sign-or-encrypt-a-message-programmatically-from-oom

I am receiving error 287 with SetProperty, assuming also due to the security policies. Am I out of luck here?

CONST PR_SECURITY_FLAGS is included in my code as required as well

Answer (score 0):

The page you are referring to contains incomplete DASL name of the property, you must define the property constant in the following way:

```
Dim PR_SECURITY_FLAGS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003"
```

Then you may set that property to the following values (bit flags) which Outlook understands:

```
NONE | 0x0000 | Message has no security 
ENCRYPTED | 0x0001 | Message is encrypted 
SIGNED | 0x0002 | Message is signed 
SIGNED | ENCRYPTED | 0x0003 | Message is signed and encrypted
```

The `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` allows setting these property values. You may try setting that property to the `NONE` constant.

But keep in my that the `PR_SECURITY_FLAGS` property is not used to encrypt or decrypt messages in Outlook, it just can be used to signal Outlook how a particular item should be processed.